# How to configure font in terminal mode (none display graphic)?

Tags: fonts

I try to use Emacs in terminal mode, but when I try to checking available font `(font-family-list)`, I go `nil`.

Is it anyway to check and set font in terminal mode?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You can't change the Font from within emacs in terminal mode.
If you want to change the font you have to change your terminal font.

Assuming linux
If you are using the tty, you should change the virtual console font (see /etc/vconsole.conf  o man 5 vconsole.conf)

If you are using xterm or similar you have to change it with your .Xresources for your particular terminal emulator (or through the menu of your terminal emulator if it has such as konsole)